# Increment column IDs by 1 in insert into statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table I want to insert into based on two other tables.

In the table I'm inserting into, I need to find the Max value and then do +1 every time to basically create new IDs for each of the 2000 values I'm inserting.

I tried something like

```
MAX(column_name) + 1
```

But it didn't work. I CANNOT make the column an `IDENTITY` and ideally the increment by one should happen in the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` statement.

Many Thanks!

Comment: mysql doesn't have "identity", so is this postgres? Use appropriate tags and don't spam unecessary ones.

Comment: Not sure why you included both mysql/postgresql in question, also I think you need provide more details.

Comment: it wouldn't let me post the question with only postgresql as a tag, but yes, it's postgres

Comment: how would i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable with the last value from the table and put it on the insert statement, like this:

DECLARE @Id INT
SET @Id = (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM YoutTable ORDER BY DESC)

INSERT INTO YourTable VALUES (@Id, Value, Value)

Answer (score 1):

If its mysql, you could do something like this..

```
insert into yourtable 
select 
@rownum:=@rownum+1 'colname', t.* from yourtable t, (SELECT @rownum:=2000) r
```

The example to generate rownumber taken from [here](http://jimmod.com/blog/2008/09/09/displaying-row-number-rownum-in-mysql/)

If its postgresql, you could use

```
insert into yourtable 
    select t.*,((row_number() over () ) + 2000) from yourtable t
```

Please note the order for the select is different on both the queries, you may need to adjust your insert statement accordingly.

Comment: mysql or postgresql ?

Comment: postgres, sorry. i removed the mysql tag now, it finally let me

Comment: if its dynamic, is it coming from another query or where would you get that?

Comment: yes, well basically the values i'm inserting depend on how many already exist in the table I'm inserting into, so it's a variable number. i just need to find the max in that column and add 1 every time somehow

Answer (score 1):

Use a sequence, that's what they are for.

```
create sequence table_id_sequence;
```

Then adjust the sequence to the current max value:

```
select setval('table_id_sequence', (select max(id_column) from the_table));
```

The above only needs to be done once.

After the sequence is set up, always use that for any subsequent inserts:

```
insert into (id_column, column_2, column_3)
select nextval('table_id_sequence'), column_2, column_3
from some_other_table;
```

---

If you will never have any any concurrent inserts into that table (but only then) you *can* get away with using `max() + 1`

```
insert into (id_column, column_2, column_3)
select row_number() over () + mx.id, column_2, column_3
from some_other_table
   cross join (
      select max(id_column) from the_table
   ) as mx(id);
```

But again: the above is **NOT safe** for concurrent inserts.

The sequence solution is also going to perform better (especially if the target table grows in size)

Comment: i will try this, i think i get it